# cannot start dbeaver on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu-18.04, dbeaver

**Prelim:** I installed dbeaver on ubuntu 18.04. Unfortunately I can't remember how exactly I installed it, but I think I followed the instructions [here](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-dbeaver-on-ubuntu-18-04-ubuntu-16-04-debian-9/). I also remember that I had problems installing the latest java version. Here some output from the command window:

```
$ java -version
java version "9-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+130)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+130, mixed mode)
```

**Problem:** I can't get Dbeaver to run. When I start dbeaver from the terminal I get the following:

```
$ dbeaver
2019-06-23 21:51:30.368 - Create display
```

and then a whole set of errors along the lines of

```
(DBeaver:15178): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:51:30.414: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed

(DBeaver:15178): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:51:30.414: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed
```

and the list goes on endlessly. Then at the end of the endless outputlist it goes:

```
2019-06-23 21:51:30.643 - > Start org.jkiss.dbeaver.core [6.1.0.201906091949]
2019-06-23 21:51:30.648 - DBeaver 6.1.0.201906091949 is starting
2019-06-23 21:51:30.649 - OS: Linux 4.15.0-47-generic (amd64)
2019-06-23 21:51:30.649 - Java version: 9-ea by Oracle Corporation (64bit)
2019-06-23 21:51:30.649 - Install path: '/usr/share/dbeaver'
2019-06-23 21:51:30.649 - Instance path: 'file:/home/myname/.dbeaver4/'
2019-06-23 21:51:30.650 - Memory available 80Mb/1024Mb
2019-06-23 21:51:30.667 - Starting RMI server at 59084
2019-06-23 21:51:30.755 - Run workbench
2019-06-23 21:51:30.769 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt [0.14.500.v20190214-0851]
2019-06-23 21:51:30.771 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.core.services [2.1.400.v20181215-2145]
2019-06-23 21:51:30.774 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts [1.8.0.v20190214-1713]
2019-06-23 21:51:30.789 - > Start org.eclipse.e4.ui.services [1.3.400.v20190212-2214]
```

and then:

```
2019-06-23 21:51:30.828 - Internal error in workbench lifecycle
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.core.application.DBeaverApplication.start(DBeaverApplication.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-ea/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-ea/Method.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1449)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:411)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.7.100.v20180817-1215
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-ea/ClassLoader.java:419)
    ... 25 more
```

Eventually it gives up after a fierce struggle:

```
2019-06-23 21:51:30.834 - DBeaver is stopping
2019-06-23 21:51:30.835 - Stop RMI server
2019-06-23 21:51:30.863 - < Stop org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.mssql.ui [1.0.9.201906091949]
2019-06-23 21:51:30.863 - < Stop org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.mssql [1.0.104.201906091949]
2019-06-23 21:51:30.863 - < Stop org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.oracle [2.1.95.201906091949]
2019-06-23 21:51:30.863 - < Stop org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.ui.tipoftheday [1.0.16.201906091949]
```

What to do? How do I get dbeaver to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [eclipse issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533390#c1) with Java 9+ that was fixed in newer Eclipse versions. I suspect the dbeaver version you downloaded probably used an older version which still has the problem. Either:

- Try installing Java 8 instead of Java 9.
- or install a newer eclipse, and the dbeaver plugins on top of that

Comment: that was a great hint! I tried to install the latest eclipse and found that eclipse didn't run properly. Why? Because of issues with Java, which I don't understand and don't want to understand. Then I tried your first guess and installed another Java version, namely Java 11. Then I restarted eclipse, which was successful. Then I tried to start dbeaver again, et voila! ca marche! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some updates suddenly my dbeaver was not opening in Windows, to fix it , I went to below location C:\Users\NikhilKamani\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6

and deleted metadata folder and started dbeaver again and it worked

Note: If you delete metadata you will have to add driver again when you try to access your databse.